# PHP - numeric value as key in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

**Example array:**

```
Array
(
    [en] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [default_locale] => en_US
        )

    [es] => Array
        (
            [active] => 1
            [default_locale] => es_ES
        )

    [de] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [default_locale] => de_DE
        )

    [fr] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
            [default_locale] => fr_FR
        )
)
```

I need to get **key** off array where **active** is **1**.
I know i can just loop through array and find it, but isn't there some better way?

I'm messing with:

```
array_search('1', array_column($array, 'active'));
```

and instead of named key, I'm getting its numerical position, in this example it is `1`, but i would need `es`.

And finally `$array[1]` doesn't output anything.

Comment: Is there supposed to only be one key with active=1? Because your example has 2. Should it return both `en` and `es`?

Comment: $array[1] should be empty - the array keys in the main array are character strings, not integers.

Comment: @iainn means that you have two active languages, which one should it return or both `en` and `es`?

Comment: @iainn Sorry, it was typo. Only one active can be at a given time. Will correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use for loop. Considering you have only one active language. If you have more than one, first occurrence will be taken.

```
$array =  array(
    'en' => array('active' => '0', 'default_locale' => 'en_US',),
    'es' => array('active' => '1','default_locale' => 'es_ES',),
    'de' => array('active' => '0','default_locale' => 'de_DE', ),
    'fr' => array('active' => '0','default_locale' => 'fr_FR', )
);
// get all the keys of your array
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
// serach for active language
$search =  array_search('1', array_column($array, 'active'));
// named key
$named_key = $array_keys[$search]; // returns 'es' in this case.
// print your active array
print_r($array[$named_key]);
```

Out put:

```
Array
(
    [active] => 1
    [default_locale] => es_ES
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ravinder Reddy's great answer; since we know the `default_locale` contains part of the key in your array, just extract `active` and index with `default_locale` and then take the first 2 characters:

```
$key = substr(array_search('1', array_column($array, 'active', 'default_locale')), 0, 2);
```

This is not a general solution and is specific to this array structure and it only returns the first key where `active = 1` (`en`).

Comment: Thinking outside the cube, I like it, but i had to accept the other answer :)

Answer (score -2):

I would just use something like this iterator.  It works, and it's simple enough that there is no research project ;-)

```
<?php // demo/temp_rhymeguy.php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959599/php-numeric-value-as-key-in-associative-array
 */
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo '<pre>';

// COLLECT RESULTS HERE
$actives = [];

// TEST DATA
$main = Array
(
    'en' => Array
        (
            'active' => 1,
            'default_locale' => 'en_US'
        ),

    'es' => Array
        (
            'active' => 1,
            'default_locale' => 'es_ES'
        ),

    'de' => Array
        (
            'active' => 0,
            'default_locale' => 'de_DE'
        ),

    'fr' => Array
        (
            'active' => 0,
            'default_locale' => 'fr_FR'
        ),
);

foreach ($main as $key => $sub_array)
{
    if ($sub_array['active'] == 1) $actives[] = $key;
}
// SHOW THE ORIGINAL AND THE RESULTS
var_dump($main, $actives);
```

Comment: OP explicitly said they are looking for something different than this: "I know i can just loop through array and find it, but isn't there some better way?"

Comment: Author was looking for a "better way" but with something elementary and straightforward like this, the simple approach that works is the correct approach.  I think any team doing a code review would gently suggest that looking for another way is probably a waste of time.

Comment: So then suggest that as a comment. Posting an answer that describes how to do what the OP _doesn't_ want to do is just as much of a waste of time.

Comment: Calm down guys, everything is fine :)